# domestic vs abroad power usa

Tags: united-states, geopolitics, power

A lot of american right wing voters want the USA to be a strong international player and project power across the globe to protect american interests. But at the same time most of them also want a small government, that doesn't in any way restrict their freedom or possessions. How can this small government be combined with a global superpower. Could the USA hold a tighter grip on the world when it doesn't have one on its own people? Are there any examples of countries where a small government wields considerable power overseas?

Comment: Voters (and many politicians), in general, don't always tend to have consistent logic in their stated demands.

Comment: Also, I think this is going to only be answerable with opinion. There's no real answer to this question.

Comment: Pat buchanan. Conservative right wing. Thesis demolished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one of the issues you're touching on is the notion that, according to many on the right, *in the US* the Federal Government is supposed to be so small as to be non-existent in people's daily lives.  One of the arguments is the [Tenth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) to the constitution that states that all powers not delegated to the Federal Government are reserved for the States, and many believe that any action by the Federal Government on domestic issues needs to be opposed for the pure simple fact that, domestically, the Federal Government *shouldn't* have very much power.

In contrast, one of the specific, "[*enumerated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_powers)", powers delegated to the Federal Government under the constitution is the power to raise and support an army and navy. Article I Section 8 declares thusly:

> The Congress shall have Power To lay and collect Taxes, Duties, Imposts and Excises, to pay the Debts and **provide for the common Defense** and general Welfare of the United States; but all Duties, Imposts and Excises shall be uniform throughout the United States;
>
> [...]
>
> To declare War, grant Letters of Marque and Reprisal, and make Rules concerning Captures on Land and Water;
>
> To raise and support Armies, but no Appropriation of Money to that Use shall be for a longer Term than two Years;
>
> To provide and maintain a Navy;
>
> To make Rules for the Government and Regulation of the land and naval Forces;

<sub><sup>Emphasis mine</sup></sub>

Again these are powers that the US Founding Fathers *specifically* delegated to the Federal Government.  There's a lot of seesawing back and forth by politicians (and Supreme Court Justices) about what our founders meant about a lot of things, but in this case there's no guessing needed because it is spelt out pretty clearly: The Federal Government has the power to wage war on our behalf, and the States themselves do not.

I personally don't subscribe to the view that the Federal Government is powerless under the constitution to do anything domestically to improve the general welfare of US Citizens, though I *can* understand why those wishing to label themselves a conservative would want to fight against domestic programs that, in their eyes, are *not* in the power of the Federal Government to undertake.  In this worldview States need *more* power than the Feds to act domestically, not only because what may work for Arkansans may not work for Californians for a myriad of reasons (social, cultural, geographical, logistical) but also because the States are seen as the laboratories of the democratic experiment and a place where new ideas can be tested and proven on a grand scale.